# Not able to fetch data from google sheet using google sheet api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to fetch data from a google sheet api but it is responding with:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

other files which were created through google sheet api & saved in drive are readable, but when I manually create a file in drive & tries to read data it fails.

Code I'm using is this:

```
readfromURL = async (connectionObj, sheetId) => {
     const { accessToken } = connectionObj;
     const response = await axios(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/Sheet1!A1:D5`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

if need more information, please tell.

Comment: I think that the error message of `Requested entity was not found.` means that the Spreadsheet ID of `${sheetId}` is not found. So can you confirm the value of `sheetId` again? And also, when `Sheet1!A1:D5` is modified to `Sheet1!A1%3AD5`, what result will you obtain? By the way, in this case, Spreadsheet ID is different from Sheet ID. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)

Comment: I can assure sheetId is correct here. I've tried with different ID as well, that didn't work as well

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. By the way, can I ask you about the method for retrieving your `accessToken`? It's OAuth2 or Service account?

Comment: I'm using Oauth2 method here

Comment: This seems like an issue, for this reason head to the [Sheets API support](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#bugs) and open a report on Google Issue Tracker. From this side we can't help you as HTTP 404 status code means that a Spreadsheet hasn't been found. If **Sheet1** didn't exist this would've thrown a 400 status code.